# Prime Numbers / Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def isPrime(n):
    NotPrime= True
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i== 0 :
            NotPrime=True
    if n==2:
        NotPrime=False
    else:
        NotPrime=False

    if NotPrime:
        print("The number is not prime")
    else:
        print("The number is prime.")
isPrime(28)
```

Hi guys i keep getting the same output regardless if the number is prime or not. What is wrong? tia

Comment: You have a number of problems there, but the most obvious is setting `NotPrime` to `False` regardless of the results.

Comment: Don't try and divide by 1: that will always give a remainder of 0

Answer (score 1):

```
 if n==2:
    NotPrime=False
else:
    NotPrime=False
```

this code doesnt let **NotPrime** variable be **True** because it stays at the almost end. It means that no matter if **n** is prime the variable **NotPrime** will still stay False. I guess you should just delete the **else** part. Also, as Hans Kesting mentioned, you should not divide anything by 1 because the remainder will always be 0